# Please help me understand what's wrong with my question

Tags: support

[Why Smalltalk uses ~= and ~~?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894356/why-smalltalk-uses-and-for-not-equal-and-not-identical)

I rephrased the original question in order to avoid my personal opinion. However, it looks like I'm still missing something. Could someone help me see what's objectable with my question? I would also like to know whether it is just a matter of wording or the question itself is off-topic.

Comment: The comments underneath the question pretty much illuminate it: the only possible answer would be anecdotal. It's not really verifiable whether the answer is true. What exactly is true in this case? If one of the original authors spoke out to tell their story of how this got to be... what would that help you? How would we know that's actually *the* story? How could we prevent someone from impersonating the author and making something up? This overall does not fit the fact-based character of Stackoverflow.

Comment: OK. I get it. Thanks a lot. I'll delete the question.

Comment: On the other hand, there have been some Java 8 design rationale questions that were very positively received -- likely because Brian Goetz, one of the language/library designers, is active and can/does answer.  Similarly, C++ standards committee papers include 'rationale' sections (and before that, there's Stroustrup's D&E book) that factual answers can be based on.

Comment: See also [Should “why language feature designed particular way” be closed/moved?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260711/should-why-language-feature-designed-particular-way-be-closed-moved/)

Comment: I do think that your question could've been a [Good Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) one, and may have been closed too hastily. Indeed, were it still open, I would've offered an answer. As it is not, let me just briefly note here that the [use of the symbol ~ for logical negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation#Notation) goes back at least to Whitehead & Russell's [*Principia Mathematica*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica) (first published in 1910), if not earlier.

Comment: Thanks Ilmari, that's precisely the kind of insight I was looking for. I'm not going to ask why other languages use != for not equal but you really awoke my curiosity...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comments on your question explain it pretty well :

> Only the creators of Smalltalk are likely able to answer the why of this. –  Eric J.
>
> Probably because that's what the people who designed the language wanted to use. Feel free to go design your own language if you want it done differently :-) –  paxdiablo
>
> The only person(s) that can answer that are the one(s) who were part of the design team. Anyone else is just guessing why those characters were chosen for those operators. –  m-y

Unfortunately your question will only get opinion-based answers which are off topic for SE; the only way to answer your question would be to ask the designers of the language.