# What's the semantics of downvoting a support question in meta

Tags: support

I posted an off-topic question in SO. The moderators put it on hold. Then I asked for [help to better understand my mistake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283225/please-help-me-understand-whats-wrong-with-my-question?noredirect=1#comment140775_283225). The moderators responded diligently and with clarity. I learned the lesson and removed my question. However, my meta-question was downvoted. Is this normal? or does this mean that my meta-question was also wrong?

Hope this one is not off-topic.

Comment: Voting on meta *used* to mean agreement/disagreement. Its only *supposed* to mean that for [meta-tag:feature-request] now, but some people have bad habits. They could have also thought your question was of low quality, but I thought it was OK.

Comment: Meta votes don't affect rep, so there are _very different_ voting patterns. People tend to vote in agreement or disagreement (out of habit). Unless you hit -5 (total, including upvotes) I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You have that backwards.  There never was, or has been, a rule stating that votes are specifically designed for agreement, whether it be a feature request or not.  The help center was merely describing how many people choose to vote, not providing rules/guidelines for how people should be voting.  Shog has a great post on the subject; trying to find it now.

Comment: [Here's everything you've ever wanted to know about voting on meta.  And then some](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/1159478)

Comment: I'm very tempted to downvote this question.

Comment: [Meta is Murder](http://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/).

Answer (score 4):

Typically, downvotes on Meta signify disagreement. From "What's Meta":

> Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works. On posts tagged feature-request, **voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself**.

(Emphasis mine.)

Note that voting on Meta is supposed to work that way *for [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s*, but it has become more or less the same voting culture for all types of posts here. I could speculate on the reason why, but it's not really worth it; it's likely some combination of there being no reputation effects and the subjectivity of nearly everything asked here.

Also, a lot of people [have already done so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta), and there's no need to go into it any further than they already have.

What you should take away from this is that voting on Meta defies reason, and no one is forced to explain the way they vote. Posts being downvoted on Meta is nearly an inevitability due to the smaller size of the community and its collection of highly-opinionated people, so you don't have anything to worry about unless your total score drops below -5; however, if you truly want to take it into your own hands to improve your post with any feedback given to you, you definitely should.