# How can I make my question non-opinion based?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Why use assertions and preconditions when you can use guard statements, forced unwrapping and error handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442809/why-use-assertions-and-preconditions-when-you-can-use-guard-statements-forced-u)

I'm just trying to understand where/why **Apple** has added this syntax.

Would writing the question as: "What is the difference between assertions & using guard statements, forced unwrapping and error handling?" made it a better question?

Comment: You're asking why your question that's just asking for people's opinions was closed as being primarily opinion based?  That seems rather self-evident...

Comment: Your two "here" links above point to the same question.  Also, that question was written in 2009, the scope of what is on or off topic has changed since then.

Comment: Note that adding a note saying "I'm not after opinions" to your question on the main site does not affect whether the question is primarily opinion-based or not. When people judge a question to be primarily opinion-based, what they are judging is the question itself. If I ask, for instance, "What is the best programming language?" no amount of "I don't want opinions", "I want only facts", "Only write answers you can prove", etc. will make the question cease to be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @JAL Thanks, fixed links

Comment: @Louis Can you suggest how you rewrite it? I'm  not here to say everybody should shut-up because it's not an opinion-based question. I'm here saying, *I believe it's not, but if you think it is then guide me how to write it*. I have 2000 reps and active on SO. I still don't know how to write it and therefore need a **concrete answer**. Comments reiterating that it is without offering any suggestion don't address this meta question

Comment: hmmm you realize that your title says "why is this opinion based" and that your question's only question is "would writing it this way be better?". There doesn't seem to be a "please help me write it as a non-opinon based question"... people are answering what's in your post. :\

Comment: You're chastising people for explaining why your question is opinion based instead of re-writing your question for you, and claiming that they're not answering your question, when you're question is, "Why is this question considered opinion based?"  Sorry, but explaining why your question is opinion based *is* answering that question.

Comment: What Servy said. Here on meta, you quickly learn not to write misleading titles.

Comment: @BoltClock you mean I should write it as: "Can you help me rewrite this question?" Or meta is not to be used that way? OR whatever I do to this question it will be opinion-based?

Comment: @Honey If that's the question you actually want to ask, then you should ask that question yes.  You shouldn't ask a completely different question than the one you want to know the answer to and then get upset at people for answering the question you actually asked.  Now, if you ask people to help you make your question not opinion based they may not be able to, not all questions are salvageable, but if that's what you want to know, that is indeed what you should ask.

Comment: Honestly, it's not unreasonable to ask why your question is opinion-based - there's nothing wrong with trying to understand how the site works, so long as you're willing to learn. But as you're less interested in the why and more so in the how, your title should just ask *how* you can make your question not opinion-based. People tend to take question titles quite literally on Stack Overflow. I know I do, even if I didn't for this particular title.

Comment: @BoltClock why are people still (after Servy's edit I received 3 more votes for close & more downvotes) downvoting the question? Is this still a bad question for meta? I thought you said it's not unreasonable...

Comment: @Servy is this still a bad question—even after your own edit? I don't get it...

Comment: @Honey My edit just removed noise from your question.  There's no point having "edit" or stricken through text all over your question; it adds nothing of value.  Anyone who wants to see what the question once read can see the revision history.  I don't think it's a particularly good question, no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: @gnat FYI BoltClock who's a moderator (in the comments above) said it's not unreasonable to ask such a question...

Answer (score 9):

**You have edited your question since my initial answer.**

> I'm just trying to understand where/why **Apple** has added this syntax.

Asking why Apple added a feature to a language is off-topic, since only Apple engineers and language architects can answer a design decision like that.  There are several meta posts on the subject.  Here are two that were found today:

[Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334/2415822)

[Should "why language feature designed particular way" be closed/moved?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260711/2415822)

> Would writing the question as: "What is the difference between assertions & using guard statements, forced unwrapping and error handling?" made it a better question?

Possibly, but there are so many different types of cases each language construct can handle that the question may be too broad to be answered in a single Q&A pair.  The issue ultimately comes down to the fact that there are many ways to handle errors with all of the language constructs provided by Swift.

**Original answer:**

I voted to close the question as primarily opinion-based.

To me, you're asking why someone would use `assert` or `precondition` instead of an `if let` or `guard` statement.  Besides the fact that these programming constructs accomplish different things (`assert` can be used for any boolean expression, not just for unwrapping optionals), ultimately the question of why Apple has added a programming construct can only be answered by Apple engineers, not by anyone on Stack Overflow, and why anyone would use it would be up to the taste and style of the programmer.  Matt even says this in his example:

> Assertions are for things that should never go wrong, and about which we feel so strongly that we don't want the program even to be released into the world under these circumstances.

Where do you draw the line?  It sounds like those circumstances can vary across program type and the opinions of the programmer.

Comment: Your logic is ultimately Apple engineers should answer. Without such a mindset, everything is to be answered by Apple developers and we should be silent about it.

Comment: If you're asking "why did Apple include `assert` and `precondition` when the same thing can be accomplished by other control flows" can only be answered by Apple.  None of us can answer why Apple made the design choices they did with Swift.  Read the language proposals and the mailing list.

Comment: @Honey How does that follow?  Only Apple can answer the question of, "Why did Apple choose to do X?"  Many other questions can be answered by anyone, not just Apple.  That *this particular question* can only be answered by Apple doesn't mean that *all* questions can only be answered by Apple.

Comment: If you ask "what is the reason a language was designed this way by its designers".... yes, you will need the designers of the language to answer it...

Comment: @Patrice do you need Apple engineers to tell why they also have structs vs. classes? why we should also use switch statements instead of if-else?

Comment: @Honey I don't know IOS and couldn't code on it to save my life, so not really sure how to answer that. However, it doesn't change much. If you want to know WHY a language was designed a certain way.. then yes you need the person who designed it. If your other questions link the same way into the fundamental design of the language... then yes, we need the designers to answer authoritatively.

Comment: @Honey If you want to know why they added structs and/or classes to the language, yes, you have to ask them.  If you want to ask a specific question about, say, how to do X with a `struct`, then you wouldn't need to be from Apple to answer such a question, anyone could have the knowledge of how to do that thing, and would be able to provide such an answer.  Asking whether you prefer using a `switch` or an `if`/`else` is asking for opinions; it's not a question with an objectively correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer per BoltClock and Servy's suggestions I edited my question entirely

Comment: @Honey I've updated my answer.