# Why was my question put on hold as "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

Look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912330/rationale-behind-using-namespace-behavior). Can anyone explain to me, why was it put on hold? Why is it too broad?

I've asked this question in the comments, but none of the people who put it on hold answered. Why is a question, which (supposedly) can be answered less than a A4 page, considered "too broad"?

What can I do to reopen it? I cannot edit the question, as I have no clue what is the problem.

I think putting a question on hold should be much harder for reviewers. And even, if they do it, they should really explain it, not just putting "too broad". Why isn't there a mechanism to communicate with the people who put your question on hold?

Comment: ' they should really explain it': no time, too many bad questions, OP's job to read the help, tour, guidelines, find out what problem is with questions and fix it.  'Why isn't there a mechanism to communicate with the people who put your question on hold?'  - they don't want to hear from you - they are too busy doing other stuff, eg. answering good questions.

Comment: Maybe it would be a better fit on Computer Science?   Not sure..

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: yes, when the question is clearly bad, then it's OK. But, I asked the reason in the comments (when there was 3 votes for on hold), so at least 2 other people, who voted, **ignored** my question. This is frustrating. Maybe, 5 votes are few. The system could have take 20 votes, and it has to be 80% percent of votes to put on hold without any explanations. But if it is just over 50%, then an explanation must be written.

Comment: *so at least 2 other people, who voted, ignored my question* They probably didn't want to have the argument that's happening in the comments on the answer.

Comment: @BSMP: That's great. If one can't defend their point of view, then just be quiet.

Comment: It's not realistic to supply explanations for down, up or close votes to tens of thousands of questions.  That's why the voting exists.  The down/close voting flags that posters have perceived a problem with the question - it must be the OP's responsibility to work out what the problem is from what comments there might be, SO rules/help/policy/meta etc.  IMHO, asking for what might be seen as trying to outsource research for contributions to a paper is a good reason for a close vote.  SO users are not research slaves.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: I'm not doing any paper, nor research. Anyway, thanks for responding. You're one of the few people who actually care. Anyway, I still think that there should be a mechanism (for the questioner) to discuss why a question is closed. I do really think that closing my question was a mistake. There were other "what's the rationale behind" questions on stackoverflow, and they are quite useful.

Comment: The question is fine, as far as I'm concerned. I'd vote to re-open, but it's already been re-opened. You cannot please everyone. Some people would prefer that this site was a "debug-my-code" website. Other people *like* the more conceptual questions. A mix of both is ideal. There are plenty of C++ experts here that can answer these types of questions. (That said, I've still downvoted *this* Meta question because I disagree with virtually all of your other claims, like that putting questions on hold should be more difficult.)

Comment: @CodyGray: thanks! Can you point me to a direction so I can understand, why do you disagree with the meta things? As I see, putting a question on hold is too easy. 5 people click (who 
may not experts at all) , and boom, your question is on hold. For controversial cases, it should be more difficult. To me, this system is far from perfect.

Comment: B/c there are far too many garbage questions that never get closed. It is a problem of scale. There are vastly more questions getting asked every minute than there are users with sufficient privileges to deal with them. I didn't say the system is perfect, but restricting it because mistakes are *occasionally* made is throwing the baby out with the bathwater. Notice the system is also self-correcting: questions that are erroneously closed can get reopened, and *did* in this case. What more could you want? I actually want to make closing *easier*. (But, granted, for experts: gold badge holders.)

Comment: @CodyGray: I see, and I agree mostly. What I experienced is that it seems to be easy to throw the baby out with the water. And I'm not sure, if I don't make this meta question, would my question have been reopened? This system makes any question to be closed very easily, and it seems very hard to get it reopened. No communication is possible with the reviewers. For this question, which have been reopened, I don't want anything more, thanks for the support. In the future, a better system would be good: garbage questions should be closed more easily, but controversial ones harder.

Comment: You don't need to communicate with the reviewers. The 5 people who voted to re-open your question are all different from the 5 people who voted to close it. No evidence that anyone changed their mind, they just got overruled. I don't know how you implement a system where garbage questions are closed more easily and controversial questions are harder to close. Someone has to decide which ones are garbage, which is itself a controversial decision. In this particular case, the problem is really just a larger disagreement in the community about whether these "why" questions are even on-topic.

Comment: @CodyGray: yes, in the current system, I don't need communication. In a better (I think) system, I could convince the reviewers to reopen it. It is frustrating that I cannot speak with the people who put my question on hold. About garbage: there could be some time limit. If a question put on hold with 100% agreement, then put on hold. If it is less than 80% percent, then it will be put on hold after a week, if no answers given with positive votes/accepted answers. Just an idea. There is little space here to discuss this, I'm afraid.

Comment: @CodyGray: or, maybe, there could be a system, where people with much higher reputation tend to get reviews which has controversial judgement by lower reputation members. So in these cases, a more experienced programmer could decide the outcome (actually, there could already a system like this in place, I don't know the internal algorithms behind the review system)

Comment: No.  The free time of skilled and experienced developers should not be flushed away down some appeal/review toilet pan ;((

Comment: 'It is frustrating that I cannot speak with the people who put my question on hold.' - you really want to talk to them?  Initiate a chat with them?  I guess that some system could be arranged, but I guess it would be opt-in and quite expensive, and you would probably be expected to escrow $$$ up front to ensure prompt payment to the engineers who close-voted you.

Answer (score 5):

"What is the rationale" sounds like a question that the language designer/implementors would have to field, and that's not something that we can tackle.  We can wave and gesticulate in front of white boards all day if we wanted to, but we wouldn't be able to give you *the* definitive answers as to why the language was written in the way it was.

Comment: I disagree. For example, one could show examples, where the rationale behind this can be seen. Pro/Cons can be shown. Plus, I've seen several former/current c++ committee members here. Why take away the possibility for them to answer?

Comment: We outnumber the committee members. We're also actually active here, whereas one of them may be on once in awhile.  Further, we're back to gesticulating at a whiteboard again.  Examples aren't valuable if you aren't explaining *the* reason.  We tend to shy away from "why'd they do it like this" questions because, quite literally, **we** can't answer them.

Comment: examples can show you the reason. Actually, even I can construct an example, where a rationale can be clearly seen (see the linked post in the question, it is actually an example). Do you really say that we never should ask a question which ask a rationale behind something? Because there are 99.9% people, who don't know the answer, so let's ignore the other 0.1%, who actually know.

Comment: I've seen several questions in 2 weeks, where I **know** the answer for a question, but I couldn't answer it, because reviewers closed it. I understand that the reviewer didn't understand the question, but I **did**.

Comment: @geza consider giving a read to [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601) "Yes, any reasonably-competent programmer familiar with the topic can daniel their way to a solution, but..." etc

Comment: @gnat: Thank you. I agree, that it is a good thing, if a question+answer is useful for future readers, not just for the original asker. However, in my case, the question is on hold before any answer was given. How can a reviewer be sure that no useful answer will be given? Actually, I got 4 upvotes before they put on hold my question (and if I'm not mistaken, it takes 5 people to put a question on hold). This means something, I think. I would understand, that if after a month, there were no useful answers, then close my question, to not pollute SO. But this is not the case.

Comment: @geza No, an example can justify a *guess* as to what the rationale is, but it's still a guess, no matter how well reasoned. Unless there is a quote from the folks who created the standard explaining why they wrote it that way, anything anyone else says is a guess because no one here is psychic.

Comment: @BSMP: You **guess** that other people will just **guess** on the answer. You cannot know.

Comment: @BSMP: Have a look at c++'s Koenig Lookup. The standard doesn't explain its rationale. Was this rationale asked by a lot of people? Yes. In stackoverflow? Yes. Was the answer useful? Yes. Was the answer an opinion? No. Was the answer a guess? No. Really, why close a question which could be answered? I really don't understand. People just downvote my question, but no acceptable answer was given to my question yet. Here's another opinion about "why" questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260711/should-why-language-feature-designed-particular-way-be-closed-moved

Comment: *"and that's not something that we can tackle"* Why not? We have plenty of answerers who are or have been on the C++ standards committee, and even if we didn't, lots of these proceedings are documented in proposals, annotated standards, blogs, etc.

Comment: @CodyGray well, it might have helped if the OP had summarized and linked what s/he had already found when diligently researching those proposals, annotated standards, blogs etc. before posting on SO...

Comment: That *always* helps, @ThingyWotsit. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray:  I don't deny the fact that they visit Stack Overflow, but my points still stand; we greatly outnumber them and we cannot rely on their presence being here at all times.  Furthermore, until they actually *do* answer a question, all we're going to be able to do is [again] gesticulate at a whiteboard.  Ultimately, that sort of question is best suited for their mailing list and not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I disagree with this gesticulating at a whiteboard thing. I don't know if you fail to distinguish between "providing logical, reasoned arguments, informed by an expert understanding of the language's semantics" and "gesticulating wildly", or perhaps if you just tend to gesture a lot when making arguments, but these two things are quite distinct to me. Furthermore, I philosophically disagree that we should be deeming questions "off topic" out of a concern that we don't have the requisite number of experts to answer them. We should be able to *replace* mailing lists for programming questions.