# Posted kind of opinion based question, then edited, but still closed later

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, opinion-based

Why is [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873557/any-examples-where-defining-the-string-type-on-the-constant-string-gives-a-typ) still closed even after my edit?

Comment: Because your edit didn't improve the question.

Comment: OK. Can you point on exactly why is my question still opinion based?

Comment: see also: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: @gnat thanks. But I'm not sure that it is the same thing. I'm a bit confused. First I asked "give me the explaination, the reason what is the benefit of something (and users downvoted as being opinion based)", then I asked for "any (that is at least one) example where the benefit of something is seen" and it is Closed because examples are not allowed. Seems like there is no way to ask a question on SO last 5 years.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I answered a few asked more recently than that.

Answer (score 4):

Asking about why particular constructs from a certain language design are designed as they are, [is on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260711/should-why-language-feature-designed-particular-way-be-closed-moved).

Do note that people tend to read the title of your question first, and your title suggests you're looking for a (possibly infinite) list of examples, while you just want one explanation. I'd suggest renaming it to something like *"Why does TypeScript allow type widening for constants?"*, and then someone will probably explain a relevant passage from the specs.